# how do I group by two columns and provide a sum of the grouped items

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building an inventory database and it has 2 columns that I would like to group by (manufacturer and model). How would I group by these columns and provide a sum of the items group?

For example:

```
Qty  Manufacturer  Model
1    Sony          MF-2002
1    Sony          MF-2002
1    Planar        PL2410W
1    Planar        PL2410W
1    Planar        PL2410W
1    Planar        PL3610D
1    Planar        PL3610D
```

Result:

```
Qty  Manufacturer  Model
2    Sony          MF-2002
3    Planar        PL2410W
2    Planar        PL3610D
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming an `Item` model, you can pass an array to the `group` method as follows:

```
Item.group(["manufacturer", "model"]).sum(:qty)
# => {["Planar", "PL2410W"]=>3, ["Planar", "PL3610D"]=>2, ["Sony", "MF-2002"]=>2}
```

Comment: The keys that come back in the response are strings that look like this:
`"[\"Planar\", \"PL2410W\"]"`
Is there any Rails magic that will split that string so that I can get each of those values? or do I have to write my own parsing code to do that?

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150608/ruby-convert-string-array-to-array-object?lq=1). Just a simple `JSON.parse`. That was easy.