# Ruby convert string array to array object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to import my CSV file to my database, my CSV file has following string and I need to parse it to a Ruby array object, how to do that?

```
"[\"Mt Roskill\", \"Sylvia Park\"]"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That example string looks like JSON. Use [`JSON.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse-21) to return a Ruby array:

```
require 'json'

JSON.parse("[\"Mt Roskill\", \"Sylvia Park\"]")
#=> ["Mt Roskill", "Sylvia Park"]
```