# Extract symbols from an Array that has been converted to a String?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, composite-primary-key

I have the following string:

`s = "[:test1, :test2]"`

I want it to end up as an Array of symbols again:

`[:test1, :test2]`

I found two similar questions:

[Ruby: Parsing a string representation of nested arrays into an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477127/ruby-parsing-a-string-representation-of-nested-arrays-into-an-array)

[Ruby convert string array to array object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150608/ruby-convert-string-array-to-array-object)

But neither the JSON.parse or YAML.load work:

```
irb(main):043> test
=> "[:test1, :test2]"
irb(main):044> JSON.parse test
/Users/[...]/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/json/common.rb:216:in `parse':
unexpected token at ':test1, :test2]' (JSON::ParserError)
irb(main):045>
irb(main):045> YAML.load test
/Users/[...]/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/gemsets/rails_test/gems/psych-5.1.1.1/lib/psych/parser.rb:62:in `_native_parse': (<unknown>):
did not find expected node content while parsing a flow node at line 1 column 2 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

`eval` does work but is generally not recommended due to injection concerns.

```
irb(main):047> eval(test)
=> [:test1, :test2]
```

The only way I can find to do it is some basic string manipulation, but I was wondering if there was a better way built into Ruby that does not involve creating a custom function.

```rb
irb(main):046> test.delete("[]:").split(", ").map(&:to_sym)
=> [:test1, :test2]
```

Ruby 3.2.2 for reference.

Comment: How did you end up in this situation? (-> can you rely on spacing? the absence of symbols like `:'foo bar'`?)

Comment: Yes, I believe so, it will be a standard form, so can rely on spacing. It's actually the `self.primary_key = [:column1, :column2]` of a composite primary key table, [see the Rails docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_composite_primary_keys.html#associations-between-models-with-composite-primary-keys). Then calling `MyActiveRecordClass.primary_key` returns it as a string `"[:column1, :column2]"`.

Comment: Does `YAML.load test.delete("[\[\],\s]").gsub(':',"\n- :")` meet your needs?

Comment: I think your existing solution is the best possible one if ActiveRecord doesn’t expose the original value somehow. You might want to edit your question to be specifically about Rails/ActiveRecord, to attract the cleanest solution to the original problem.

Comment: `"[:test1, :test2]"` is neither JSON nor YAML. While you can munge the string and parse it into an array, the problem is most likely in your view or controller. I provide a *slightly* more robust munging chain below, plus some advice on where to look for the actual *source* of your problem.

Comment: Thanks @pjs, that would be fine but I guess is not shorter/easier in the end than my simpler string parsing.

and thanks Ry- and Todd, Rails doesn't provide the original value, and I realize it's not JSON or YAML but was just mentioning because the other question I did find used those even if the original intent wasn't to have them as json/yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean up your example, but it's not guaranteed to work on anything that's not a flat array of symbols stored inside a string.

```rb
s = "[:test1, :test2]"

s = s.delete(":[]").split(?,).map { _1.strip.to_sym }
=> [:test1, :test2]
```

However, it's entirely unclear how you're ending up with a String instead of an Array of Symbols, and nothing in the Rails Guide about [composite keys](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_composite_primary_keys.html#associations-between-models-with-composite-primary-keys) explains how you're ending up in that state. I'm forced to assume you're getting data from form input or URI parameters (both of which are represented as strings) and not parsing the elements as *separate* column names so you can properly form the composite key from the two String values.

The section on [composite keys in forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_composite_primary_keys.html#forms-for-composite-primary-key-models) says that the keys must be delimited by an underscore for the Rails magic to work, and you may also need to implement `params.extract_value` in your controller to access them properly. You didn't show any controller, view, or model code, so it seems like you're trying to patch up the improperly-formatted end result instead of focusing on the source of the incorrect data.

Even if that's not the case, this is ultimately solving the wrong problem. You need to figure out why *s* contains invalid JSON, or why you aren't getting two separate keys as String objects (not Symbols) that you can then use to form your composite key properly.

Solve for those things. The post facto String munging is addressing the symptom, not the cause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm actually not using any views or controllers at this time so that's not where any problem is coming from, I am trying to make use of MyModel.primary_key elsewhere in some custom work. I tested more after posting this question and actually updating Rails from 7.0.8 to 7.1.1 returns an Array of strings now `["column1", "column2"]` so I guess Rails realized the original return value wasn't great either.

I'll mark this as accepted though because it seems like there isn't a much better way to do it given my first input than I originally came up with.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than remove bits that you don't want I suggest you extract the strings you do want (then covert them to symbols).

```
s = "[:test1, :test2]"
```

```
s.scan(/\w+/).map(&:to_sym)
  #=> [:test1, :test2]
```

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-scan) and [String#to_sym](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-to_sym).

---

If desired one could modify the regular expression slightly to confirm that each colon is present.

```
s.scan(/:\K\w+/).map(&:to_sym)
  #=> [:test1, :test2]
```

or

```
s.scan(/(?<=:)\w+/).map(&:to_sym)
  #=> [:test1, :test2]
```

Here `\K` resets the start of the match to the current location in the string and discards any previously consumed characters (`":"`). `(?<=:)` is a *positive lookbehind* that asserts that the beginning of the match is immediately preceded by a colon.

These refinements are of dubious value, however. If, for example, the string were `"[test1, :test2]"`, `[:test2]` would be returned, whereas raising an `ArgumentError` exception might be more appropriate. If the correctness of the string format were in question it would probably be more useful to perform a separate check by executing the following.

```
s.match?(/\A *\[ *:\w+(?: *, *:\w+)* *\] *\z/)
```

[Demo](https://rubular.com/r/2VtcdlcK2UegTD)<sup>1</sup>

This regular expression can be expressed in *free-spacing* mode to make it self-documenting.

```
/
\A          # match the beginning of the string
\ *\[\ *    # match >= 0 spaces followed by '[', followed by >= 0 spaces 
:\w+        # match ':' followed by >= 1 word characters
(?:         # begin a non-capture group
   \ *,\ *  # match >= 0 spaces followed by ',', followed by >= 0 spaces
   :\w+     # match ':' followed by >= 1 word characters
)*          # end the non-capture group and execute it >= 0 times
\ *\]\ *    # match >= 0 spaces followed by '', followed by >= 0 spaces
\z          # match the end of the string
/x          # invoke free-spacing mode
```

In free-spacing mode it is necessary to protect any spaces that are part of the expression. I've done that by escaping spaces; putting each space in a character class (`[ ]`) is another common way to do that.

<sup>1. At the link I've used start-of-line (`^`) and end-of-line (`$`) anchors rather than start-of-string (`\A`) and end-of-string (`\z`) anchors in order to test multiple strings.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this great reply from the regex side of Ruby which I don't use as often as I could.